# Is removing .svn folders the same as "svn export"?

Tags: svn

Conceptually I believe that deleting all .svn folders from a project is the same as "svn export". I can delete all .svn folders if I don't want to preserve the history of a project. But I want to confirm before I do.

All Stack Overflow posts talk about preserving the history and using tools like rsvndump. But I don't want to preserve, and I am curious, why am I better off using "svn export"? Or am I?

Comment: Perhaps you could answer this for yourself by creating a copy of your work tree and deleting all of the .svn files, then doing an export along side it, and running `diff` on the pair of directories to see if there are any differences?

Comment: Hmm... Why didn't I think of this.. thanks.. I'm doing it now.

Comment: SVN 1.7 has only one `.svn` folder per working copy, BTW. http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#single-db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result will be same.
Use

```
svn export
```

if you do not need the history since it faster than

```
svn checkout
remove .svn  files
```

Comment: Since you answered much earlier than me :), accepted your answer. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Export creates a replica of the project without (.svn) file.
Yes if you don't want to preserve the history .svn export is a good option.

Answer (score -1):

I ran a `find -type d -name '.svn' -exec rm -rfv {} \;` on my project folder, did a commit, and it worked perfectly.

I also did a `svn export` on a different project and did commit. It worked perfectly.

Edit: I never work in the checkin folder. I instead copy all files to a different folder called `workinprogress`. When I need to checkin, I compare using meld so that I know file by file, line by line what I am committing. This also helps me keep notes for my checkin. I ran the above test in my workinprogress folder.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  There's no way you can commit if you remove the .svn directories from your working copy.  Nor can you commit from an export.

Comment: You misunderstood, if I remove all .svn folders it becomes a new project. And my question is very clear `I dont want to preserve` the history, which inturn means I need a new project in my svn. I hope I have clarified.

Comment: Right I get you don't want to preserve history, but the answer as written above it's not really clear that you're copying the files to a different working copy.  It implies that you're trying to commit them out of the working copy you removed the .svn dirs or the export from.  You can destroy history without even moving things between repositories by just using the OS copy commands rather than the svn copy command.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer to make it more accurate. I hope its correct.